# Prevent kendo datagrid export to excell download dialog

Tags: javascript, excel, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I need to save the Excell file restult from exporting a kendo datagrid, into a database, making an ajax request (POST) to the server. So, I suscribed to the `excelExport` event of the datagrid. This is the code I use for this:

```
var grid = $("#myGrid").data("kendoGrid");
grid.bind("excelExport", exportGridAsExcell);
grid.saveAsExcell();

function exportGridAsExcell(e) {
        e.defaultPrevented = true;
        var dataUrl = new kendo.ooxml.Workbook(e.workbook).toDataURL();
        var base64 = dataUrl.split(";base64,")[1];

        //make an ajax request with base64 variable as param
}
```

The problem is that after the exportGridAsExcell ends, the browser shows a DownloadDialog. I don't want this. How can I archieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like e.defaultPrevented = true; doesn't work in your situation, try to use code from telerik docs [source](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/excel-export#saving-files-on-server)

```
 $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        toolbar: ["excel"],
        dataSource: {
            type: "odata",
            transport: {
                read: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Products"
            },
            pageSize: 7
        },
        pageable: true,
        columns: [
            { width: 300, field: "ProductName", title: "Product Name" },
            { field: "UnitsOnOrder", title: "Units On Order" },
            { field: "UnitsInStock", title: "Units In Stock" }
        ],
        excelExport: function(e) {
            // Prevent the default behavior which will prompt the user to save the generated file.
            e.preventDefault();
            // Get the Excel file as a data URL.
            var dataURL = new kendo.ooxml.Workbook(e.workbook).toDataURL();
            // Strip the data URL prologue.
            var base64 = dataURL.split(";base64,")[1];
            // Post the base64 encoded content to the server which can save it.
            $.post("/server/save", {
                base64: base64,
                fileName: "ExcelExport.xlsx"
            });
        }
    });
```

Here is "working" example on dojo  [click](http://dojo.telerik.com/aSeZay/2) , just press excel export button and look at console output

Comment: I changed `e.defaultPrevented = true` for `e.PreventDefault()` and it solved the problem